# Usage of "tierisch" in a book title

Tags: grammar, adjective-ending

A children's book has the title "*Mein tierisch tolles Bildwörterbuch Deutsch*".  The word *tierisch* in the title confuses me a bit.

I would have the book title as "*Mein tierisch**es** tolles Bildwörterbuch Deutsch*".  What is the reason for dropping the "*-es*"?  Is tierisch an adverb or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"tierisch" is an adverb in this case and qualifies "tolles". You can write "tierisches" but then it would qualify "Bildwörterbuch". So by writing "tierisch tolles" you mean something like "sehr tolles" - "very great", to keep it simple, and by writing "tierisches tolles", you would mean something like "animalistic and great".

Answer (score 0):

*Tierisch* acts as a qualifiyer of *toll*: Not simply amazing, but animalistically (?) so.